# Rectangle in Scrollview is not visible

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I've created a new project and added a scrollview with a rectangle. When I start the project the rectangle is not displayed but if I add an other control it appears. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I want to see the rectangle always.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    id: mainWindow
    ScrollView{
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: 0
        anchors.bottomMargin: 0
        width: 289
        Rectangle{
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "blue"
            MouseArea
            {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: console.log("Click")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this code I get the following window (rectangle is not visible):
[image]

However if I add a button to this ScrollView...

```
 ScrollView{
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: 0
        anchors.bottomMargin: 0
        width: 289
        Rectangle{
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "blue"
            MouseArea
            {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: console.log("Click")
            }
        }
        Button{
            text:"Test"
        }
    }
```

The rectangle appears:
[image]

What's wrong with my first code (without the button)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ScrollView` has two sizes, the size of the control view in the UI, and the size of the content of the `ScrollView`.

When you add the `Rectangle` without the `Button`, you instruct the `Rectangle` to fill its `parent`. The `parent` in this case is the content of the `ScrollView`. By default that content is empty, and you've instructed the `Rectangle` to fill this empty space. Therefore there is nothing displayed.

When you add the `Button` which has an explicit size, it forces the content of the `ScrollView` to be non-empty, so now the `Rectangle` has something to fill, thus you see it.

Comment: So I can't make the rectangle visible without adding an other control to the scrollview? It is really weird.

Comment: No, you can make the `Rectangle` visible if you give it a size. In your sample you configured the `Rectangle` to fill the content of the `ScrollView`. If the `ScrollView` has no content, then the size of that content is 0x0. Therefore the size of the `Rectangle` is 0x0.